# I got wrong date from SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-conversion

I have this piece of code:

```
String sDate = "2018-12-01";
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(sDate);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy - EEEE");
sDate=sdf.format(date);
```

When i run this code on my pc, everything is fine.
But if i run on another pc, date is 1 day earlier than my expected.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: check the timezone

Comment: Yes it's about timezone. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It’s weird, though. When you don’t specify time zone for any of the `SimpleDateFormat` objects, they should both use your JVM’s default time zone, so the date should be the same (01 December 2018 - Saturday — the language depending on your default locale). I tried your code in all available time zones and got `01 December 2018 - Saturday` each time.